# Hi! I need to highlight cells with "cat" and "3" (in all interpretations: 13, 23, 31, 32, 33 etc.) in yellow

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

[image]

I used this formula in conditional formatting:

```
=IF(SEARCH("3";LEFT($A1;FIND(" ";$A1)-1);1)>0
```

But it doesn't work.

How to properly format cells?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `=IsNumber(search("3", A1))`

Comment: Not a good sample pic as you have "3" for both dog and cat on the same line.

Comment: @T04A19 I have posted as answer. Please accept it to close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight those cells contains 3 at any place of string then use below formula to conditional formatting.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("3",A1))
```

If you want only `Cat` having 3 then use below formula.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("3",FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>",2)&"</s></t>","//s[1]")))
```

[image]

Comment: Would this be only available with the newer versions of excel?

Comment: It is available on Excel2013 and later.